# Visual Studio takes a lot of time to build a Xamarin app and it doesn't happen

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm using Visual Studio 2019 Version 16.9.3 when I try to build my Xamarin forms android app it takes a lot of time to build and nothing appears on the error list or emulator. it's still in the build step forever, doesn't move to the emulator I tried a lot of tips and tricks like

*restart your IDE.
*reinstall your IDE.

- delete obj and bin files
  *some sittings on tools > option... and Nothing happens my output

  "Build started... 1>------ Build started: Project: App8, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------ 1>App8 -> C:\Users\moham\source\repos\App8\App8\App8\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\App8.dll 2>------ Build started: Project: App8.Android, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------ "

**notes:**

- this happens on all projects in xamarin not only one project
- I am debugging on android 10 API 29
- my emulator is my phone
- all packages in the last update
- this problem started since update Visual studio to 16.9
- I report a problem in the Microsoft community they told me to reinstall the IDE but nothing happens

Can someone please help me??

Comment: you have asked some variation of this question 3 times in the past day.  Please do not post duplicates.

Comment: You can try to repair your Visual Studio.For more details, you can check:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio?view=vs-2019 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to repair your Visual Studio.A repair is useful for fixing install-time issues across all install operations, including updates.

For more details, you can check:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio?view=vs-2019 .

If the problem persist, try to perform a thorough uninstall for Xamarin for Visual Studio.
For more details, check docuemnt: [How do I perform a thorough uninstall for Xamarin for Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/troubleshooting/questions/uninstall-xamarin-vs) .